# Autohiding the top bar and the bottom bar in Gnome Classic?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

I don't know how to achieve this.  From what I have read, `Alt + Right Click` or `Super + Alt + Right Click` should work, but neither shortcut works. The problem is that when applications are fullscreen, neither bar is ever visible, even when pressing `Control + Alt + Tab` (like I did with GNOME 2), therefore I hope that by making them autohide, this problem will go away. I am using GNOME 3.14.1.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In **Debian Armbuntu** there is a setting in the "Settings Editor" application.
Open it with *Applications > Settings > Settings Editor* and select the sub-setting: **xfce4-panel**

In the tree, look for *panels > panel-1 > leave-opacity* and set it's value to 0.

This will allow it to appear and disappear upon mouse movement.